# Почему реакт не перерендривает компонент по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useAsyncEffect(async() => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const data = await res.json()
    setUsers(data)
  }, [])
  console.log(users)

  const count = Object.keys(users).length;

  function sortCity() {
    users.sort((x, y) => {
      if (x.address.city < y.address.city) {
        return -1
      }
      if (x.address.city > y.address.city) {
        return 1
      }
      return 0
    })
    console.log(users)
  }

  function sortCompany() {
    users.sort((x, y) => {
      if (x.company.name < y.company.name) {
        return -1
      }
      if (x.company.name > y.company.name) {
        return 1
      }
      return 0
    })
    console.log(users)
  }

  <
  SortButton button = {
    sortCity
  }
  text = "по городу" / >
    <
    SortButton button = {
      sortCompany
    }
  text = "по компании" / >
```

Comment: Скорее всего при нажатии не изменяется ваш стейт

Comment: Разве Функция sortCity не изменяет users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стейт нельзя изменить просто меняя значение переменной, для изменение стейта нужно передать новое значение в `setUsers`. Метод `sort()` как раз меняет значение `users`, поэтому реакт не видит изменений.

Функция сортировки может выглядеть примерно так:

```
  const sortCity = () => {
    setUsers((prev) =>
      [...prev].sort((x, y) => {
        if (x.address.city < y.address.city) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (x.address.city > y.address.city) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      })
    );
  };
```

В данном случае в `setUsers` передается функция, которая принимает аргументом предыдущее значение стейта и возвращает новое значение. При этом, перед сортировкой нужно создать копию массива.